# Typedef using templated nested class within a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, nested, typedef

So I have SkipList.hpp which has a nested templated class called SkipListIterator.

```
//SkipList.hpp
template <class Key_t, class Mapped_t>
class SkipList {
    template <bool isConst, bool isReverse>
    class SkipListIterator {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In my Map.hpp, I want to make typedefs for the different types of iterators. What I tried to do was the following:

```
//Map.hpp

#include "SkipList.hpp"
template <class Key_t, class Mapped_t>
class Map {
    typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::SkipListIterator<false, false> iterator;
    typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::SkipListIterator<true, false> const_iterator;
    typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::SkipListIterator<false, true> reverse_iterator;
    typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::SkipListIterator<true, true> const_reverse_iterator;
    ...
}
```

This does not work, and g++ gives me the following error:

```
error: non-template 'SkipListIterator' used as template
typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::SkipListIterator<false, false> iterator
                                            ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with gcc 6.3.1:

```
template <class Key_t, class Mapped_t>
class SkipList {
    template <bool isConst, bool isReverse>
    class SkipListIterator {
    };
};

template <class Key_t, class Mapped_t>
class Map {
    typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::template SkipListIterator<false, false> iterator;
    typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::template SkipListIterator<true, false> const_iterator;
    typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::template SkipListIterator<false, true> reverse_iterator;
    typedef typename SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::template SkipListIterator<true, true> const_reverse_iterator;
};
```

When working with templates, the compiler often needs extra help to figure out what it is type, a template, or a non-type.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly quick answer, worked perfectly!